# Error al configurar PHPMailer

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de configurar el PHPMailer y me presenta esta serie de errores.

**Warning: require(PHPMailer/src/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\emailer\sendemail.php on line 5**

**Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\emailer\sendemail.php on line 5**

==============================================================================

mi código es el siguiente:

==============================================================================

```
    <?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    
    //Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                      //Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'andreymolina91@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'supersecret';                               //SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
    
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('andreymolina91@gmail.com', 'Opcional');
        $mail->addAddress('alema0@misena.edu.co', 'Andrey Molina Dev');     //Add a recipient //Name is optional
    
        //Attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name
    
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Prueba de proyecto Emailer';
        $mail->Body    = 'Uso de librerias PHPmailer <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Mensaje enviado';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error inesperado: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
    
    ?>
```

Ya revisé que los required estén en la ruta especificada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no pusiste bien tu ruta, pusiste la ruta de ejemplo que te mostraba en el repositorio en github, en vez de la ruta en tu computadora, **solo edita las que dicen require las otras no las toques**.

```
 require 'carpeta donde se encuentra tu archivo Exception.php/Exception.php';
 require 'carpeta donde se encuentra tu archivo/PHPMailer.php';
 require 'carpeta donde se encuentra tu archivo/SMTP.php';
```